# Развертывание standalone Java приложения на heroku

Tags: java, heroku

Нужно запустить на сервере телеграм-бота, написанного на Java (наиболее знаком с этим языком). В дальнейшем подключится к базе данных, для записи всех нужных данных, а пока нашел в интернете простейший пример, с использованием библиотеки от *Rubenlagus*:

Main.java:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new HelperBot());
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

HelperBot.java:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramApiException;

public class HelperBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

public String getBotUsername() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "name_bot";
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "token";
}

public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Message message = update.getMessage();
    if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
        if (message.getText().equals("/help"))
            sendMsg(message, "Привет, я робот");
        else
            sendMsg(message, "Я не знаю что ответить на это");
    }
}

private void sendMsg(Message message, String text) {
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
    sendMessage.setReplayToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
    sendMessage.setText(text);
    try {
        sendMessage(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

После деплоя на *Heroku*, с использованием плагина *heroku-maven*, библиотека *API* подключена из локального репозитория, все файлы загружены, но приложение не работает.

Меня интересует, можно ли подобного рода приложения заставить работать на сервере или посмотреть в сторону других вариантов? (если да, то каких?)

Локально все запускается, работает и отвечает на запросы как положено, а вот на *Heroku* не хочет.

В логах написаны все успешные билды. После сборки никаких ошибок не выскакивает, в том числе после попытки обращений к боту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Занимался практически такой же задачей пару дней назад, у нас проблема оказалась в том, что бесплатный Dyno был отключен, и приложение запустилось только после запуска привзяанного Dyno. Если у вас в логах нет вообще ни стрчоки от приложения - это верный признак того, что приложение просто не было физически запущено.

Если вас интересует непосредственно Procfile, то его содержимое может быть таким:

```
worker: java -cp target/classes:/target/dependency/* Main
```

Comment: Ознакомился с Procfile, добавил его в свой проект. Теперь действительно, в логах появились записи. Правда несмотря на указание в MANIFEST и maven shade plugin, в логах написано о невозможности найти или загрузить main class

Comment: @Vladimir у нас это решилось указанием package для соответстующего main-класса

Comment: Разобрался после того, как еще раз прочел документацию по Procfile.    Его итоговое содержимое:    `worker: java -jar target/JARNAME.jar com.package.my.Main`  Запускаю сразу jar после сборки на сервере через    `mvn clean heroku:deploy`   Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Сам недавно задавался этим вопросом, помогло подключение библиотеки через maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.pengrad</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-telegram-bot-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
  <id>jitpack.io</id>
  <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: библиотеку использую другую, она также подключена как maven-зависимость. На сервер загружается (судя по локальному клону), в процессе билда ошибок не выдает.